# How to implement a Chat application to interact with a Teams BOT

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I have written a chat BOT which works fine when I interact with it directly from Teams or from the BOT Framework Emulator.

However what I would like to do is interact with it from a Web Application.

Can anyone offer any guidance on how to do this. What Api should I use, are there any samples etc.

Just about all the documentation for writing chat applications seems to be about writing the *BOT* end.  I need to implement the *user* end

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on your ask?

Comment: One way to look at this would be to consider how to implement a chat client in a Web Application.

Answer (score 2):

If this is your own web application, that you control (i.e. source code), then this could be a good starting point: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat